# How to update static library architecture for supporting armv7k architecture (WatchOS2)?

Tags: ios9, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos, watchos-2-beta3

I have our own created static-library (Universal) that work's fine with Watch OS SDK 1.0 as watch extension runs on iOS but after updating transitioning my app to OS2 that is not working. i tried to change valid architecture & "BUILD_ACTIVE_ARCH_ONLY = NO" as googlers suggested but nothing is working. I am converting ogg to wav using my static library. please suggest me any possible solution for either fixing this problem or converting ogg to wav in iWatch, Thanks !!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your static library with the same SDK in the version of Xcode that you're building your watch app?

Comment: @OwenHartnett Yes i did. but same clang error i am getting "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7k"

Answer (score 0):

When I look at my Valid Architectures, in the build settings, I see arm64, armv7 and armv7s.  Perhaps you have added the "k" inadvertently?  Otherwise, compare the build settings for architectures for your iOS app, library, and watch kit extension.

Comment: Tried but no luck. I think watch os2 architecture is having only arms7k as valid arch.
http://i.imgur.com/n4yjn0Z.png

Comment: You're right armv7k is set for the watchkit app and watchkit extension. Can you add armv7k to the architecture list in the build settings when you build your static library?